# How to dynamically insert Google adwords Heading and description to landing page?

Tags: php

I am trying to implement a solution to have my landing page display the adwords adds.

I followed the instructions here:

http://www.davewooding.com/google-adwords-dynamic-keyword-insertion-php-script/

But I can't get it working....

Following the tutorial I inserted this code into my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html?$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

The .php file has this code as instructed:

```
<?php

// default
$replace = "Thailand";

if (isset ($_GET ['q'])) {
$replace = preg_replace("/-/" , " " , $GET['q']);
}

$title = ucwords(strtolower($replace));
$h1 = ucfirst(strtolower($replace));

?>
```

I have created a page to link to it for testing:

http://xuzo.com/link.html

And the destination testing page is at:

http://www.xuzo.com/dynamic.php

Comment: Consider adding `htaccess` tag to this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your implementation, make the following change in your .htaccess.

WAS:

RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html?$ index.php?q=$1 [L]

IS:

RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html?$ dynamic.php?q=$1 [L]

Comment: Hi Dave, I changed the code as requested, but still not working....is my testing method appropriate by linking link.html page to dynamic.php ?